# Fastest way to bulk upload files to google bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bucket

I have large number of pdfs to upload to google bucket.
What is the fastest way to upload all these files to google bucket?
I have tried uploading using drag and drop but it's taking a lot of time should I create a python script or is there any faster way to bulk upload data to GCP bucket.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not exactly python related, but [`gsutil cp`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) might be helpful, since it has a parallel option `-m`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/), specifically the `gsutil cp` command.

Comment: Also, the -m switch enables parallel upload which makes the entire operation way faster.

Answer (score 0):

Now it's recommended to use [gcloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/discover-object-storage-gcloud)

e.g

```
gcloud storage cp Desktop/kitten.png gs://my-awesome-bucket
```

as per [doc](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/)

> Generally, you should use gcloud storage commands instead of gsutil commands